# Dump/Edit File System of Forerunner 35

Tags: filesystems, embedded, binaryfiles, ida, garmin

I have been trying to modify/add to the internal file system or operating system of the Garmin Forerunner 35 watch. I have had no luck so far, and am stuck.

So, the watch [appears as a drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlAmy.jpg) (E) when plugged into a pc, but when I put a software update binary into IDA, [you can see a path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt1Gx.jpg) that is not present in the E Drive in the strings view.

I am looking for a way to view/dump/edit the file system of the watch, be it through a specially crafted software update or other means.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Added pictures

Answer (score 1):

The `E:` drive you see *is* the Garmin's internal filesystem.

Paths you can see in an executable using `strings`-type tools can be debug records put there by the compiler.  In this case, `..\..\..\TSK\garmin-os\tsk_mem.c` appears to be a reference to part of Garmin's source code, which you won't be able to find on the device (or online).

One way to modify the behaviour of the system is to put `.FIT` files into the `\GARMIN\NEWFILES` directory on the Garmin; when it starts up it processes these files and can make modifications.

For example, to enable heart rate variability (HRV) tracking *on some devices only*, [see these instructions](https://sporttracks.mobi/blog/tracking-hrv-garmin-watches):

> To enable HRV recording you need to do the following:
>
> 1. Connect your watch to a computer with the supplied USB cable
> 2. Download `enable_hrv_settings_file.fit` [link in original article]
> 3. Put that file into your watch in this folder: \GARMIN\NEWFILES
> 4. Sync your watch with Garmin Express and disconnect

Finally, if you want to modify the operating system itself, you should be looking at the firmware update mechanism.

Updating the firmware involves getting a `.GCD` file, then:

> 1. Copy the file into the `\GARMIN` directory
> 2. Renaming it to `GUPDATE.GCD`
> 3. Disconnect the device from the computer
> 4. Approve the update on the device
> 5. Wait for the update to finish

There is some discussion on online forums such as [gpspassion.com](http://www.gpspassion.com/) about the format of these files, such as [in this post](http://www.gpspassion.com/forumsen/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=115804), which gives:

`[main header]
[descriptor]
080000FF
data block 0xFF00 sized ...*n times (data=RAMloader)
0800xxyy
last data block sized 0xyyxx.
[descriptor2]
BD0200FF
data block *n (data=fw_all)
BD02xxyy
last data block sized 0xyyxx.
+something last bytes...`

You can find archives of `.GCD` files online.